# Is it possible to deform a curve according to a cloth?

Tags: bezier-curves, cloth-simulation, geometry, hook-modifier

For example, take this red cloth that's been hooked by the empty's. There's a green curve with geometry right on top of it.

[image: Cloth with curve on top of it]

Is there any way for the curve to deform according to the cloth, when the empties are moved? I'm trying to create an embroidery effect

If not, is there some sort of workaround for this?

As an extra question, could I move an objects in relation to a vertex on the cloth, like a button being sewn on?

Thanks for any help

Comment: For your second question, you can parent an object to 3 vertices of your cloth: Select your button, shift select your cloth, switch to Edit mode, select 3 vertices and press Ctrl P > Make Vertex Parent. As for the curve it will be easier to deform if it's a mesh I guess

Comment: Thanks for answering! I don't need to keep the curve as a curve, so how would I deform it if it was converted into a mesh according to how the cloth is deformed?

Comment: You can use the Shrinkwrap modifier either on a curve or on a mesh object.

Comment: The *Shrinkwrap* modifier only works with the original mesh, not with the mesh that is deformed by the *Cloth* modifier. For this purpose you need the *Surface Deform* modifier (which requires a mesh).